# "Failed to de-alias project." error when listing gcp secrets with gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I have the following error when I do the command `gcloud secrets list`:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.secrets.list) HttpError accessing 

<https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxxxx/secrets?alt=json&pageSize=100>: response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'date': 'Wed, 26 Apr 2023 13:38:37 GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=xxxx,h3-29=":443"; ma=xxxx', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': 500}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Failed to de-alias project.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
>
```

I do not find any info on this `Failed to de-alias project` error. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Secret Manager is currently experiencing an outage. See their status page here: https://status.cloud.google.com

This error does not come from your side and is happening for all (or most) GCP projects. It will be resolved automatically as soon as this issue is addressed by Google's teams.